# Prove that $f$ is differentiable (polynomial),

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial in $n$ variables, i.e. 
>   $$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{k_1,\ldots, k_n =0}^{m} a_{k_1\ldots k_n} x_1^{k_1} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$$
>   for some coefficients $a_{k_1\ldots k_n}$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable.

It looks pretty obvious but I am not sure how to start the proof.

Comment: It is even smooth.

Comment: Start with the definition of "differentiable"?

Answer (score 4):

First prove that each
$$
g_j:x\longmapsto x_j
$$
is differentiable, and that every constant function is differentiable.

Then prove or recall that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then $fg$ and $f+g$ are differentiable.

Your function is built on products and sums of the $g_j$'s and constant functions. So it is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just show that each $x_i^k$ is differentiable, so the sum of their products are also differentiable.