# Prove that the polynomial $f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ is differentiable for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, polynomials, solution-verification

A prove [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318812/prove-that-f-is-differentiable-polynomial) is given. However, I am needing to prove this using the definition of differentiable. That is, I am only allowed to use the definition of the derivative and *not* my "knowledge" of constants and functions of the form $x^j$ where $ j\geq 1$ being differentiable. Here is the question:

*Question*: Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ be a polynomial and recall that if $f(b) = 0$, then $f(x) = (x - b)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. Use this to prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable at all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here is my approach.

*Proof*. Assume $f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ is a polynomial and that $f(x) = (x - c)q(x)$ for $q(x)$ being some polynomial and for $c$ being a root. Using the definition of differentiable we have
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        f'(x) &= \lim\limits_{x\to c}\left( \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \right) \\
        &= \lim\limits_{x\to c}\left( \frac{(x - c)q(x)}{x-c} \right); \quad \text{c is a root} \\
        &= \lim\limits_{x\to c}\left(q(x) \right) \\
        &= q(c)
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Note we went from the penultimate line to the last line because we know that polynomials are continuous for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. QED.

Is this proof a valid proof?

Comment: There is one assumption, which is not necessarily true. 
**Hint**: What happens if $f(x)=x^2+1$?

Comment: I see, then there is no root $c \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, we have complex roots.

Comment: If your proof is correct, you're showing that a polynomial is differentiable at a root. Not everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is incorrect $f(x) = (x - c)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$  is only true if $f(x)$ has a root at $c$ but the polynomial may not have a root at the place your differentiating .

Solution

$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to c}\left( \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \right)$

To solve the problem using the way asked in the question use the fact that $f(x)-f(c)$ has a root at $c$

Comment: You are right, a more general observation is that $f(x)$ need not necessarily have a root in $\mathbb{R}$ at all

Comment: @Summand yes for example $x^2+1$ , to solve the problem one can use $f(x)-f(c)$ instead since it has a root at $c$

Comment: I see now. I am not sure though how to proceed with the idea of using the fact "f(x) - f(c) has a root at c". Maybe I am not really sure what it means when $f(x) - f(c)$ has a root at $c$.

Comment: @Owen if $f(x)-f(c)$ has a root at $c$ then it will equal to $(x-c)q(x)$ and now you can use the same reasoning as In the question .

Comment: @Vivaan Daga, So, in my proof given, instead saying $f(x)$ has a root at $c$, I should have stated that $f(x) - f(c)$ has a root at $c$ where $f(x) - f(c) = (x - c)q(x)$? And then proceeded from there?

Comment: @Owen See Wikipedia of  the remainder theorem for why for any given polynomial $k(x)$ with a root at $m$ there will always exist another polynomial $z(x)$ such that $k(x)=(x-m)z(x)$. As to your second question yes .

Comment: @VivaanDaga I see. I will read and about it and try to internalize it. Thank you very much!